# Linear independence for modules over a zero ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

I'm going to assume here that all rings have $1$.

> Let $M$ be a left $R$-module. A subset $I$ of $M$ is *linearly independent* if $r_1m_1 + ... + r_nm_n = 0$ implies $r_1 = ... = r_n = 0$ for all $r_1,...,r_n \in R$ and $m_1,...,m_n \in I$. A basis of a left $R$-module $M$ is a linear independent subset which generates $M$.

However, I don't see this definition working well for modules (actually, for *the* module) over a zero ring. Indeed, it is known that $\varnothing$ generates a zero module and it is trivially linearly independent. But $\{0\}$ is also linearly independent if $R = \{0\}$ for $r_1m_1 + ... + r_nm_n = 0$ implies trivially that $r_1 = ... = r_n = 0$ for the only element of $R$ is $0$. Since $\{0\}$ is commutive, the IBN property of commutative rings breaks: free module over them no longer have a well-defined dimension: for an $\{0\}$-module $\{0\}$ has bases of cardinalities both $0$ (namely $\varnothing$) and $1$ (namely $\{0\}$).

So, what am I missing (if anything)?

Comment: From Wikipedia, a commutative ring with 1 \neq 0 has IBN.

Comment: Right, IBN doesn’t hold for the zero ring. Does some question remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right that the zero ring does not have the IBN property. Note also that the usual proof of “the IBN property of commutative rings” relies on the existence of a maximal ideal, which fails for the zero ring.

(One takes a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $R$ and then considers for any free $R$-module $F$ the extension of scalars $(R/\mathfrak{m}) \otimes_R F$.
Any $R$-basis of $F$ gives an $(R/\mathfrak{m})$-basis of $(R/\mathfrak{m}) \otimes_R F$ of the same cardinality.
Now one uses that $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field to argue that the dimension of $(R/\mathfrak{m}) \otimes_R F$ is well-defined.)